# Passing token/session values from one application to its sub application

Tags: authentication, sso

My client currently has an existing ASP.NET web portal, which runs fine. It's hosted on their on-premise IIS Server. I will call this one the "parent application".

Now I'm working on another web application which has less functionality and is intended to be embedded with their "parent application". This will be hosted as virtual directory under the same IIS application. I will call this one the child application.

We are not going to implement any authentication in the child application. Instead, the parent application will be authenticated and from there the child application can be invoked. The child application should only work based on valid user session/tokens.

What would be the best way to implement this session/token passing from the parent to the child application? Also, I'm not sure whether this would fall under SSO (Single Sign On)?

Comment: Is the "main web portal" and the "parent application" the same thing?